# Мeaning between 'принудить,' 'вынудить,' 'заставлять'

Tags: значения

In my view, these three words seem to be the most common words to express the verb 'to force' or 'impel.' But I don't feel like I have the best grasp on how they are differentiated from one another and when to appropriately use them. Could their individual distinctions be explained?

Answer (score 4):

1.**Принудить** (к чему-либо, реже: сделать что-то) - the source of this action is always human, and they definitely do so with intention. It is often about making somebody to do what they are supposed do. This verb is typically used together with a noun in dative case.

```
принудить к даче показаний, к отдаче долга, к мирным переговорам
```

2.**Вынудить** (сделать что-то) - the source of action "вынудить" is not necessarily human, and if human then not necessarily they expect a particular result, which is expressed using another verb (infinitive).

```
Понизив подчинённого в должности, он вынудил его искать другую работу. 

Обстоятельства вынудили его уехать.
```

3.**Заставить** (сделать что-то) - when the source of action here is human, the action "заставить" is intentional and aimed at a particular result,  which is expressed using another verb (infinitive). If not human, then the meaning is that some circumstances made somebody to do something particular (more likely without any choice between multiple evils, than in case of вынудить, but the meaning is almost the same):

```
Он заставил матроса взять ветошь и вымыть гальюн.

Обстоятельства заставили его поступить именно так.
```

Answer (score 3):

The most neutral and least agressive is `заставлять`:

> Мама заставляет сына заниматься в музыкальной школе.
>
> Как ты заставляешь себя столько тренироваться?

`принудить` has a bit official tone, it's used in documents, for example:

> Противника принудили сесть за стол переговоров.

And `вынудить` has less formal meaning, with a tone of extortion:

> Они вынудили его подписать сделку поглощения.
>
> Он вынудил подростка пойти на место преступления.

Answer (score 0):

```
Legend:
==========================
unLgc  = unlogical
wSnds  = weird sounds
sImp   = some imperfections
taut   = tautology



                    Examles                           | Differences
------------------------------------------------------+------------------------
Его никто не заставлял, он вынужден был сделать это.    Ok
Его никто не заставлял, он принужден был сделать это.      unLgc 
Его никто не заставлял, он заставлен был сделать это.      wSnds & unLgc

Его никто не принуждал, его принудили сделать это.         unLgc
Его никто не принуждал, его вынудили сделать это.          unLgc
Его никто не принуждал, его заставили сделать это.         unLgc
Его никто не принуждал, его вынудили 
                        сделать это обстоятельства.     Ok

Его никто не вынуждал, его ...                            all unLgc

Его принудили, и он вынужден был сделать это.              sImp, taut
Его принудили, и он принужден был сделать это.             utter taut
Его принудили, и он заставлен был сделать это.             (1), or a bit taut

Его вынудили, и он вынужден был сделать это.               sImp,a bit taut
Его вынудили, и он заставлен был сделать это.              wSnds
Его вынудили, и он принужден был сделать это.              sImp, (1) 
Его вынудили обстоятельства, и он принужден
                               был сделать это.         Ok, (1)

Его заставили, и он принужден был сделать это.             sImp, (1) 
Его заставили, и он вынужден был сделать это.           Ok
Его заставили, и он заставлен был сделать это.             wSnds


----------
(1) здесь мы подразумеваем два действия над объектом.
```